# PHP curl resets content-length if CURLOPT_POST is set with curl_setopt_array?

Tags: php, curl

It looks like `curl_setopt_array` is different from just multiple invocations of `curl_setopt`. Consider this script:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.stackoverflow.com/');

[options]

curl_exec($ch);

var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

Now it sends a proper request if `[options]` are one of these:

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_POST => true,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('a' => 'b'),
));
```

or

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('a' => 'b'),
));
```

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'a=b');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

**BUT NOT this way:**

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('a' => 'b'),
  CURLOPT_POST => true,
));
```

It seems that the content-length is reset if `CURLOPT_POST` is set after `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Except it works ok if set with `curl_setopt` instead of `curl_setopt_array`.

Why is this?

Comment: Excellent work tracking this down. Now I can stop banging my head against the wall and upload photos through Facebook's API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify `CURLOPT_POST`, the post is sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

But, from the `curl_setopt` manual page:

> Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will encode the data as
>   multipart/form-data, while passing a URL-encoded string will encode
>   the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

So when you do

```
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('a' => 'b'),  // multipart/form-data
  CURLOPT_POST => true,                     // application/x-www-form-urlencoded
));
```

The data is being set as `mulpart/form-data` (by setting `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to an array) and then reset as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (by setting `CURLOPT_POST` to true).

The other examples work because you're not changing the type once the data is set.

Comment: but when I do the same with `curl_setopt` (last example), why does it work?

Comment: because both options set the type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so the data is not lost

Comment: Oh, I see, my bad. At this point I think that it is better to just omit `CURLOPT_POST` at all, the data type will be set based on post fields. Is that correct?