# Posting data with curl to secure page

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to post pin and number of giftcard to BarnesAndNoble site to get the available balance. (we are a company buying gift cards from people, and we need to verify the balance)

https://cart2.barnesandnoble.com/gc/gc_ViewBalance.asp

The weird thing is that, the content returned is the original page (not the resulted page where it should say the pin&number entered are invalid, or should return an amount)

I wonder why it doesn't work, the code is pretty straight forward

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $formUrl = 'https://cart2.barnesandnoble.com/gc/gc_ViewBalance.asp ';
    $ckfile = __DIR__.'\cookie.txt';



    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $formUrl);        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $formUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);   

    $urldata = parse_url($formUrl); 
    $headers = array("Host: ".$urldata['host']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

    // tried this as well 
    //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__)."/GTECyberTrustGlobalRoot.crt");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return content as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);;
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

[PHP curl resets content-length if CURLOPT_POST is set with curl_setopt_array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979854/php-curl-resets-content-length-if-curlopt-post-is-set-with-curl-setopt-array)

Long answer: read the above link
Short answer: pass the query string into CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS instead of an array (I used array in the above $post)