# CURL + POST + multipart/form-data

Tags: php, forms, curl, multipart, form-data

I am trying to scrape a website using PHP, CURL and POST method in order to submit a form before web scraping the page. The problem I am experiencing is that there is connected with POST method: no data is submitted to the server, so the scraped webpage doesn't contain what I am looking for.

I quit sure the problem is connected with the form type: enctype="multipart/form-data".
How can I manage this POST request, considering that the form is multipart/form-data?
Do I have to encode the post_string in a special way?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
 function curl($url) {

//POST string
$post_string="XXXX";

$options = Array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,  
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE, 
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE, 
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,  
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120, 
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8",  
        CURLOPT_URL => $url, 
        CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__)."/cacert.pem",

        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_string,

    );

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);   
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);       
    return $data;   
}

$scraped_page = curl("XXXURLXXX");    
echo $scraped_page;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the CURLOPT_POST to true:

```
CURLOPT_POST = true
```

Then fill your post fields like this 'setup':

```
$postfields = array();
$postfields['field1'] = 'value1';
$postfields['field2'] = 'value2';
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields
```

---

> If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data.

[The PHP manual](http://php.net/curl_setopt)

Comment: Well,
I've added these lines:

CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($postfields),

and filled post fields with your setup, but it still doesn't work: Firebug confirms that no POST is executed...

Comment: Firebug will not show the real POST as this happens 'inside' the PHP execution, not inside the 'output' of the page.

Add the following to your PHP, after the $data = curl_exec($ch); ==> 
var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));

And see what that will show.

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you, but the page which is "echoed" still shows the empty form and no results..

Comment: Hmm. Some people recommend to just do this, without the http_build_query function:
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields

And I found out why:
http://nl1.php.net/curl_setopt
"If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data."

Comment: I'm only saying what PHP will do, if this does not work, and if we cannot test this code locally, it's the best thing we can do :) :|

Comment: I've edited the code as you suggest: now, if I put CURLOPT_POST = true AFTER CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields, I receive "Bad Request (Invalid Number)"...while, if I put CURLOPT_POST = true  BEFORE CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields, nothing special happens (the form page is echoed)...

Comment: It looks like there is a difference indeed. Maybe try to NOT specify CURLOPT_POST and only setting CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS? Worth a try.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979854/php-curl-resets-content-length-if-curlopt-post-is-set-with-curl-setopt-array

Comment: Without CURLOPT_POST no error messages, but the scraped webpage contains only the form and no results.
May I show you the code, so you can test it locally? 
Here it is (please, do not paste the scraped URL, it's quite confidential): http://pastebin.com/p4CeZVuQ

Comment: OK. I see this example redirects (HTTP CODE 302) because it's URL is HTTP and not HTTPS. So I used HTTPS and 'bypassed' SSL checks to make it work. Check it out, with this one I do get results back: http://pastebin.com/64NV22fV (pastbin will expire in 2 weeks)

You can remove CURLOPT_HEADER, I used it for debugging, also the var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $post_string needs to be an array.

Also set CURLOPT_POST to true.