# Php Curl issue with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS on put request

Tags: php, curl

Testing my application using php 5.5.13 and curl 7.36.0, I had success with this request:

```
public static function httpPut($url)
{
    $query = self::concatUrl($_POST);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . self::getCookiesPath());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . self::getCookiesPath());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("ipAddress: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 200 && curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 201)
    {
        throw new Exception($output, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($output);
}
```

But on the server, using php 5.3.3 and curl 7.21.0, I'm having a issue with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
```

It simply don't send any data on the request.
To get success I need to concat $query with $url:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url . " ? " . $query);
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Try adding Content-Length header: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Length: " . strlen($query), "ipAddress: " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));`

Answer (score 0):

By doing

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url . " ? " . $query);
```

you are simply making a GET request not POST request.

I am not sure what `self::concatUrl` is doing but are you sure its making a valid key value pair for POST request?

Then you have not specified the length of the data.

Please have a look at this answer:
[PHP curl resets content-length if CURLOPT_POST is set with curl_setopt_array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979854/php-curl-resets-content-length-if-curlopt-post-is-set-with-curl-setopt-array)